# How to Mock this using MSTest and Moq

Tags: moq, mstest

I'm just learning how to use Moq, with MSTest. I have the following method I want to test, in an existing applicaton:

```
/// <summary>
/// Return the marker equipment Id value give a coater equipment Id value.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="coaterEquipmentId">The target coater</param>
/// <returns>The marker equipment Id value</returns>
internal static string GetMarkerEquipmentId(string coaterEquipmentId)
{
    return CicApplication.CoaterInformationCache
        .Where(row => row.CoaterEquipmentId == coaterEquipmentId)
        .Select(row => row.MarkerEquipmentId)
        .First();
}
```

The **CicApplication** object is a 'global' object with a property named CoaterInformationCache, which is a List of CoaterInformation classes.

I assume I will need to mock the CicApplication.CoaterInformationCache somehow, and I probably need to pass this method an interface containing the list of CoaterInformation classes, instead of accessing the list via a global object that only contains values at runtime?

Thanks very much

Comment: Being global or static isn't the tough part; it's not having the property be an interface, and having no way to set it that's the real problem.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Horn. Very insightful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Globals / statics are a bane for unit testability. To make this testable, you're correct in that you should eliminate the `CicApplication` global. You can create an interface, i.e. `ICicApplication` with the same public API, and pass an instance into your application code.

```
public interface ICicApplication
{
    public List<CoaterInformation> CoaterInformationCache { get; }
}

public DefaultCicApplication : ICicApplication
{
    public List<CoaterInformation> CoaterInformationCache
    {
        // Either use this class as an adapter for the static API, or move
        // the logic here.
        get { return CicApplication.CoaterInformationCache; }
    }
}
```

Since this is a static method, you could pass it as a method argument, otherwise, convert the static method to an instance method an initialize a `ICicApplication` field on the object (perhaps pass an instance into the constructor).

Then, when you set up your unit test, you can pass in a mock instance set up with Moq:

```
Mock<ICicApplication> appMock = new Mock<ICicApplication>();
appMock
    .SetupGet(ca => ca.CoaterInformationCache)
    .Returns(new List<CoaterInformation> { ... });
```

Comment: Scott - If I eliminate the CicApplication global and create an interface with the same API, what will implement the interface?

Comment: @RandyMinder: You will need to create a default implementation for the interface, using your current static logic. I've updated my answer to include a sample implementation.